# Custom model for spacy 3.0 implemented using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, spacy, spacy-3

I have searched and searched. I was able to find [this git repository](https://github.com/explosion/projects/tree/v3/tutorials/rel_component) that puts a thinc model as a relationship extractor pipeline in spacy. I need to add my NER model which is implemented using Tensorflow as a Spacy pipeline and I don't know what is the difference between adding a custom model implemented using thinc and with TensorFlow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify: the repository you linked does not showcase a Pytorch model for relation extraction in spaCy - in fact it uses the ML library [Thinc](https://thinc.ai/) to implement the model. You can find more details on that in the corresponding [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HL-Ap5_Axo).

The key point to remember is that spaCy works with Thinc models under the hood, but Thinc provides [wrappers](https://thinc.ai/docs/usage-frameworks) for Pytorch and Tensorflow.

To use those in spaCy, you can follow the documentation [here](https://spacy.io/usage/layers-architectures#frameworks). In a nutshell, you should be able to do something like this:

```
from thinc.api import TensorFlowWrapper
wrapped_model = TensorFlowWrapper(your_tf_model)
```

The `wrapped_model` will now be a `Thinc` model that you can use to power your (custom) [trainable pipeline component](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#trainable-components).

Comment: Is wrapping the model enough in order to use the model in spacy as a pipeline? Do I have to override forward and backward functions for the wrapped model?

Comment: A functional model will work within the wrapper, you won't need to implement any more bwd/fwd functions. To use the model within a spaCy pipeline though, you have to use it within an existing or a custom trainable pipeline component (https://spacy.io/usage/layers-architectures#components)